# Special matrix: formed by sides of tetrahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, normed-spaces

I have a tetrahedron formed by some points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$.

Form (column) vectors $ \vec{v}_1 = P_1 - P_4, \vec{v}_2 = P_2 - P_4, \vec{v}_3 = P_3 - P_4$ that represent three edges of the tetrahedron.

Form a matrix $A = [\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3]$.

What can be said about its operator norm if the length of each vector $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2, \vec{v}_3$ is not greater than one? Is there any special bound?

Comment: Which norm, the spectral norm ?

Comment: @JeanMarie see edit

Comment: One way of considering the issue is to think to the classical way one can inscribe a regular tetrahedron $T$ into a cube, by joining a set of 4 vertices that are not adjacent. If you take a cube with side length $1/\sqrt{2}$ in order that its diagonals have length 1, "your" tetrahedron could be placed inside $T$.

Comment: @JeanMarie But the tetrahedron does not have to be regular in my case. And the side length may be close to one.

Comment: I don't say that. I say that with the condition "side lengthes  $\leq$ 1", "your" tetrahedron should (I have no proof for that) be inscribed in $T$ with the advantage that all vertices' coordinates $(x_k,y_k,z_k)$ verify linear inequality constraints.

Comment: @JeanMarie If it were so, what's the consequence for the operator norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, given two normed vector space $U$ and $V$, the operator norm for a linear transform $T : U \to V$ depends on the choice of norms on $U$ and $V$.

For the $3 \times 3$ matrices at hand, we will assume the corresponding $U$ and $V$ are the ordinary $\mathbb{R}^3$ equipped with Euclidean norm.

By (one of the many equivalent) definition,
$$\|A\| 
= \sup_{u \in S^2} \|Au\|
= \sup_{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)\in S^2} \| \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + \lambda_3 v_3\|
$$
where $\displaystyle\;S^2 = \left\{ u = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \|u\| =  \sqrt{\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2} = 1 \right\}$.

Notice for $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) \in S^2$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\| \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + \lambda_3 v_3\|
&\le |\lambda_1|\|v_1\| + |\lambda_2|\|v_2\| + |\lambda_3| \|v_3\|\\
&\stackrel{C.S}\le \sqrt{\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + \lambda_3^2}\sqrt{\|v_1\|^2 + \|v_2\|^2 + \|v_3\|^2}\\ &= 
\sqrt{\|v_1\|^2 + \|v_2\|^2 + \|v_3\|^2} \le \sqrt{3}
\end{align}
$$
This implies the operator norm $\|A\|$ is bounded from above by $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: ...And this bound is reach for example with the regular tetrahedron. By the way, was it necessary to present the issue with a tetrahedron ? It could have been said : "we have a matrix $A$ whose 3 columns $v_k$ are such that $\|v_k\| \leq 1$, what can be said about the operator norm of $A$" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, for regular tetrahedron, the operator norm is $\sqrt{2}$. $\sqrt{3}$ is achieved by degenerate tetrahedron with $v_1 = v_2 = v_3$.